# Dynamically create variables in PowerShell

Tags: variables, loops, powershell

How do I create a new variable each time a loop runs?

Something along the lines of

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++)
{
    $"var + $i" = $i
    write-host $"var + $i
}
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use `New-Variable` and `Get-Variable` (mind available options including scopes). E.g.

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++)
{
    New-Variable -Name "var$i" -Value $i
    Get-Variable -Name "var$i" -ValueOnly
}
```

Comment: perfectly valid answer. I would add that anytime that I need to do something like this, I prefer to use a hash table.

Comment: I also prefer hashtables. Still, there are some (rare) cases where only these cmdlets help.

Comment: An example is in a psake block like the properties block where you need to do something REALLY dynamic.

Comment: Can you give an example of how you would answer the original question using a hashtable @EBGreen? I'm not seeing how hashtables would help for this scenario? Or can you show what alternative scenario you are referring to?

Comment: @YorSubs here is the example: `$data = @{}; for ($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++) { $data["var$i"] = $i; Write-Host $data["var$i"] }`