# Dynamic variables in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am wondering if it is possible to reference a variable in powershell by concatonating two or more pieces of data. See example below...

```
$v0 = "My Var"
$v1 = "My Var2"

$suffix = 0

#THESE EXAMPLES BELOW (ALTHOUGH WRONG) WILL ILLUSTRATE WHAT WE ARE TRYING TO DO.

Write-Host $(v($suffix)) #ERROR
Write-Host $(v$suffix) #ERROR
Write-Host v$suffix # "v0"
```

I would like this script to output "My Var". I do not think this is possible since Powershell is using .NET which is not a dynamic language. Any ideas if this is possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamically create variables in powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015303/dynamically-create-variables-in-powershell)

Comment: I think in that example they are dynamically creating the name not pointing to a variable by putting together pieces of data

Comment: Write-Host (Get-Variable "v$suffix" -ValueOnly)

Comment: @JBone Think of variable, function, alias, and environment variables names as paths (similar to filename paths) in PS. You can refer 2 an item with this syntax: <provider drive>:<path name>. Get-psdrive will give you a list of <provider drive>s. Examples `gi c:file.txt`, `gi variable:v0`, `gi env:path`, etc. Similarly these: `${c:file.txt}`, `${variable:v0}`, `${env:path}` also get an item. In last 2 you can omit braces. This illustrates paths but doesn't answer your question. For that u have 2 use provider specific cmdlets: get-variable and get-alias. They take names created by concatenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Write-Host (Get-Variable "v$suffix" -ValueOnly)
```