# Loop X number of times

Tags: powershell

I'm working on my first PowerShell script and can't figure the loop out.

I have the following, which will repeat ***$ActiveCampaigns*** number of times:

```
Write-Host "Creating $PQCampaign1 Pre-Qualified Report"
Invoke-Item "$PQCampaignPath1\PQ REPORT $PQCampaign1.qvw"
Write-Host "Waiting 1 minute for QlikView to update"
sleep -seconds 60 # Wait 1 minute for QlikView to Reload, create Report and Save.

DO{
    Write-Host "Daily Qlikview Reports"
    Write-Host "Wating for QlikView to create the $PQCampaign1 PQ Report"
    Get-Date
    Write-Host "Checking...."
    sleep -seconds 1
    Write-Host ""
    Write-Host "Not Done Yet"
    Write-Host "Will try again in 5 seconds."
    Write-Host ""
    sleep -seconds 5
}

Until (Test-Path "$PQCampaignPath1\$PQCampaign1 $PQReportName $ReportDate.xlsx" -pathType leaf)

Get-Date
Write-Host "Done with $PQCampaign1 PQ Report. Wait 10 seconds."
sleep -seconds 10
```

These parameters need to increase with one for each loop:

- `$PQCampaign1`     (should become `$PQCampaign2`, then 3, etc.)
- `$PQCampaignPath1`  (should become `$PQCampaignPath2`, then 3, etc.)

So if `$ActiveCampaigns` is set to 8 on a certain day, then this needs to repeat 8 times and the last time it must open `$PQCampaign3` which lies in `$PQCampaignPath8`.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This may be what you are looking for:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le $ActiveCampaigns; $i++)
{
  $PQCampaign     = Get-Variable -Name "PQCampaign$i"     -ValueOnly
  $PQCampaignPath = Get-Variable -Name "PQCampaignPath$i" -ValueOnly

  # Do stuff with $PQCampaign and $PQCampaignPath
}
```

Comment: It's quite hard to believe that *anything* in PowerShell is implemented as easily understandable as that...

Answer (score 146):

Use:

```
1..10 | % { write "loop $_" }
```

Output:

```
PS D:\temp> 1..10 | % { write "loop $_" }
loop 1
loop 2
loop 3
loop 4
loop 5
loop 6
loop 7
loop 8
loop 9
loop 10
```

Answer (score 42):

Here is a simple way to loop any number of times in PowerShell.

It is the same as the `for` loop above, but much easier to understand for newer programmers and scripters. It uses a range and foreach. A range is defined as:

```
range = lower..upper
```

or

```
$range = 1..10
```

A range can be used directly in a `for` loop as well, although not the most optimal approach, any performance loss or additional instruction to process would be unnoticeable. The solution is below:

```
foreach($i in 1..10){
    Write-Host $i
}
```

Or in your case:

```
$ActiveCampaigns = 10
foreach($i in 1..$ActiveCampaigns)
{
    Write-Host $i
    If($i==$ActiveCampaigns){
        // Do your stuff on the last iteration here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015303/dynamically-create-variables-in-powershell). It shows you how to dynamically create variables in PowerShell.

Here is the basic idea:

Use [New-Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/New-Variable) and [Get-Variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Variable),

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++)
{
    New-Variable -Name "var$i" -Value $i
    Get-Variable -Name "var$i" -ValueOnly
}
```

(It is taken from the link provided, and I don't take credit for the code.)

Comment: Thanks. I'll play with that a bit - but I don't think that solves my issue. My variables already exist, I just want to change the variable that is being called in each loop...