# How to get the loop working in this script?

Tags: powershell, loops

Hi I'm trying to check for a registry key and run a reg file if the registry value doesn't match.

I'm completely new to Powershell so I have some confusion about the loop commands.

here's the code:

```
$loop = start-sleep -s 15
$v1 = Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\{0406A191-78E7-4590-9C4D-AA69EE7B5073}' -Name Description
If ($v1 -ne "SOS-246") { 
Do {Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath "C:\Temp\win11-right-click.reg"
} else {
Continue $loop
 }
```

How to make it to loop?

Comment: Many examples of Powershell loops in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28733726/62576)

Comment: The code in your question is clearly not your real code. The `else` doesn't match against the `if`. Can you post the real code?

Comment: Not exactly what i'm going to do. The loop in my script need to wait for 15 second before  checking the registry value.

Comment: @Enigmativity, the point is the loop issue. I can include any codes in between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be better off with a while loop:

```
while ((Get-ItemPropertyValue -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\Profiles\{0406A191-78E7-4590-9C4D-AA69EE7B5073}' -Name Description) -ne "SOS-246"){
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 15
}
```

This loop checks your registry key for the required value, and if it does not match it waits for 15 seconds before it checks it again. You could add some logging (Write-Host) to the loop before or after the sleep so you know what it is doing.