# Dynamically create objects in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015303/dynamically-create-variables-in-powershell) (reprinting the solution below) very nicely illustrates how to dynamically create a new variable each time a loop runs:

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 5; $i++)
{
    New-Variable -Name "var$i" -Value $i
    Get-Variable -Name "var$i" -ValueOnly
}
```

I'd like to do something similar but with psobjects. Something like this (this is not working):

```
for ($i=1; $i -le 10; $i++) { 
$obj($i) = new-object psobject 
$obj($i)| add-member noteproperty value ($i) 
}
```

In this example, the expected result would be that 10 objects would be created, named `$obj1`, `$obj2` … `$obj10`.

Comment: What would you actually like to achieve? There might be a better way to accomplish what you need.  ;-)

Comment: **_generally_**, programmatically naming $Vars is a VERY BAD IDEA. there is no graceful way to know what any given $Var will be named. that also goes for a $Var that contains a single object. [*grin*] ///// the recommended [_and reasonably safe, reasonably sane_] method is to use a collection - array for small groups, `Generic.List` collections for larger ones, or some variant of a hashtable for collections that require some degree of uniqueness for whatever reason [lookup tables, sets, etc.].

Comment: @Olaf I'm working with the Spotify API, trying to create one psobject per song appearing on an album. The number of tracks per album is stored in a variable. I was thinking, in pseudocode: for i in 1 .. $numberfotracks; create $track$i and assign properties; done.  I'm new to object-oriented (I usually script in bash), so you're right, there probably is a better way!

Comment: @HubertLéveilléGauvin - instead of making one $Var per object/track ... make a collection that holds those track objects. you can make one collection per album, or add the album name to the track object and store as many albums in the collection as needed.

Comment: @HubertLéveilléGauvin - I agree with Lee_Dailey. There's no need to create a bunch of numbered variables. That would make the code more convoluted and more complex than necessary.