# Powershell | how to programmatically iterate through variable names

Tags: powershell

I have this code:

```
$a1 = "value1"
$a2 = "value2"
$a3 = "value3"
$a4 = "value4"
$a5 = "value5"

DO {
    "Starting Loop $a1"
    $a1
    $a1++
    "Now `$a is $a1"
} Until ($a1 -eq "value5")
```

i try to make the loop stop once it reach `value5`. The question is how i can go pass through all the variables, so if `$a1` is not `value5` it go to `$a2`. Thanks.

Comment: @jsotola what should the title be? "Stop Do Until loop once it reach certain variable"?

Comment: okay, i using your title suggestion lol

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically create variables in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015303/dynamically-create-variables-in-powershell)

Comment: @Griz - generally speaking, one otta not use a series of $Var names. instead, store them in a collection of some sort. that makes working thru them MUCH easier ... just use `foreach ($Item in $Collection)` ... [*grin*]

Comment: @jsotola i don't want to create new variable everytime the loop run, I have a list of variables like the one on my question, i want the loop going to every one of the variable list and stop when the variable value is `value5`. btw sorry for my bad explaination, have no idea how to explain it, hope you get it.

Comment: @Griz, what Lee_Dailey is trying to say, is that this is an odd request. Most people do not use variables in this way. Most people would use something like an array. So you would have a single variable, which contains multiple items. And then you can loop though the array. Generally when odd questions like this come up, it's because you're likely trying to solve a problem with the wrong tools.

Answer (score 2):

### <strike>What you're trying</strike> ⚠️

You might get the variables using the [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) cmdlet. By default the `Get-Variable` (and the counterpart [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable)) will include *all* known variables including other variables you created (e.g. `$b1 = "valueB1"`), [automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables) (e.g. `$args`) and everything that is inherited from a parent [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes).
Therefore you need to be very careful with these cmdlets as you might easialy retrieve *or overwrite* the wrong variable.

```
$a1 = "value1"
$a2 = "value2"
$a3 = "value3"
$a4 = "value4"
$a5 = "value5"

$a = 1
DO {
    "Starting Loop `$a$a"
    Get-Variable -ValueOnly "a$a"
    Set-Variable "a$a" "NewValue$a"
    Get-Variable -ValueOnly "a$a"
    $a++
} Until ($a -gt 5)
```

But as already suggested, **[Don't use the -Variable cmdlets for dynamic variable names!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68830451/1701026)**.

### Instead

Create a new *custom* list of variables using a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables) and read and write your values in there:

```
$a = @{}                        # create a hash table
1..5 |% { $a[$_] = "value$_" }  # count from 1 to 5 ($_ is the current item)
$a[3]                           # display the $a[3]
```

```
value3
```

Comment: Please [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer (or tell me what is missing), so that I can use it for other duplicated questions as e.g.:  [Use Dynamically Created Variable Name Within a Variable Name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65331634/1701026)