# PowerShell, select the variable that is missing a value

Tags: arrays, powershell, variables

I am trying to select the variable name from a selection of variables that is missing a value:

Only $fruit is missing "Pears" and I want to only list that.

```
$fruit = @('Apples','Oranges','Bananas')
$fruit2 = @('Apples','Oranges','Bananas', 'Pears')
$fruit3 = @('Apples','Oranges','Bananas', 'Pears')
```

So I need the code to find the variable name $fruit
but I when I try this:

```
$fruit, $fruit2, $fruit3 | ?{$_ -notcontains "Pears"} | Select $_
```

It only lists the 3 fruits in the variable that does not contain "Pears"

How do I get it to list $fruit as the result?

Comment: A hashtable keyed on Fruit, Fruit1, Fruit2 with the associated value being the array would probably be the way to go....

Comment: What exactly do you expect as a result? The literal word `$fruit`???What should be the outcome if `$fruit3` is also missing `pears` or has e.g. `lemons` instead of `pears`. Please think your question through before [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Apologies, I want the variable that does not contain the pears to be produced as the result. The actual use case is to interrogate a bunch of computers for the absence of a particular application, I tried to simplify the example to learn how to filter objects that contain a lot of things but only show the objects that have something specific missing.

Comment: $fruit = @('Apples','Oranges','Bananas'); $fruit2 = @('Apples','Oranges','Bananas', 'Pears'); $fruit2 | Where {-not $fruit.Contains($_)}

Comment: You would probably want to read this: [Powershell | how to programmatically iterate through variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65250334/1701026)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable?view=powershell-7.3) for this:

```bash
Get-Variable fruit, fruit2, fruit3 |
    Where-Object Value -NotContains Pears |
    ForEach-Object { '$' + $_.Name }

# Outputs: `$fruit`
```

What you should use instead as recommended in comments is a [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$fruits = @{
    Fruits  = 'Apples','Oranges','Bananas'
    Fruits2 = 'Apples','Oranges','Bananas', 'Pears'
    Fruits3 = 'Apples','Oranges','Bananas', 'Pears'
}

$fruits.GetEnumerator().Where{ $_.Value -notcontains 'pears' }.Key

# Outputs: `Fruits`
```

Answer (score 1):

Or using the variable: drive

```
dir variable:fruit* | ? value -notcontains pears

Name                           Value
----                           -----
fruit                          {Apples, Oranges, Bananas}
```