# Bulk-Assign PowerShell Variables using Multi-Level [PSCustomObject]

Tags: powershell, function, variables, scripting, pscustomobject

## TLDR

I'm trying to create a function that will take a **Multi-Level** **`[PSCustomObject]`**, extract the `Key/Value` pairs (`strings` only), and use them to declare **Individual Global Variables** using `Set-Variable`.

## Current Code

```
Set-Variable -Name 'NSOneDrive' -Value "D:\OneDrive - New Spectrum"
$StrykerDirs = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'OneDrive' = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'NSOneDrive'    = "D:\OneDrive - New Spectrum"
        'MyOneDrive'    = "D:\OneDrive"
    }
    'Dev' = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'DevDir'        = "${NSOneDrive}\Dev"
        'DevToolsDir' = [PSCustomObject]@{
            'DevTools'  = "${NSOneDrive}\Dev\_DevTools"
            'Terminals' = [PSCustomObject]@{
                'DT_Terminals'  = "${NSOneDrive}\Dev\_DevTools\terminals"
                'DT_PowerShell' = "${NSOneDrive}\Dev\_DevTools\terminals\PowerShell"
            }
            'Editors' = [PSCustomObject]@{
                'DT_Editors'    = "${NSOneDrive}\Dev\_DevTools\.editors"
            }
        }
        'ProjectsDir' = [PSCustomObject]@{
            'NSProjects'    = "${NSOneDrive}\Projects\NewSpectrum"
            'MyProjects'    = "${NSOneDrive}\Projects\Personal"
        }
    }
}

$StrykerDirs |
    ConvertTo-JSON -Depth 25 |
    Tee-Object -FilePath ".\JSON\Stryker-Paths.json"


function Set-DirAliases {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    # I might add parameters after I know how to make the 'Process' work
    
    Begin {
        # Begin Process Block
    }
    
    Process {
        ForEach ( $dir in $StrykerDirs ) {
            where ( $_.GetType() -eq 'String' ) |
                Set-Variable -Name "${key}" -Value "${value}"
                # I know ${key} and ${value} won't work, but I'm not sure how to properly fill them
        }
    }
    
    End {
        # End Process Block
    }
}
```

## Goals

### Simplifying `Set-Location` Navigation

First and foremost I obviously need to figure out how to make the above `Process` block work. Once I do, I'll be able to easily **declare Directory Variables for use with `Set-Location`**. This is *only* for streamlining variable declarations so I don't have to repeatedly declare them with a messy barrage of individual `Set-Variable` commands while also avoiding the use of long (sometimes *very* long) `$Object.PropertyName` 'variables'.

After I get a handle on *this* script, I'll be able to finish several other scripts and functions that use (more or less) the same basic process.

### Add to `$PROFILE`

This particular script is going to be part of a **'Startups'** section in my default `$PROFILE` (`Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`) so I can set the **Directory Variables** in-bulk and keep the `$PROFILE` script itself nice and clean.

The other scripts that I mentioned anbove are also going to be included in my `$PROFILE` **Startups**.

### JSON Output

The script also exports a `.json` file so that, among other things, I can (hopefully) repeat the process down the road in my **WSL Bash Profiles**.

### `Param()` Functionality

Eventually I want to add a `Param()` block so the function can be used outside of the script as well.

Comment: What is the question? Generally, I don't think [what you are trying to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65250334/1701026) is a good idea, I would at least keep your custom variables separated in a different (flat) hashtable and address them as e.g.: `$My.NSOneDrive`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add this to the "Goals"

I'm trying to declare variables for the current session to simplify navigation using `Set-Location`

Comment: Also as far as setting a 'flat' `[PSCustomObject]` or Hash Table, I will resort to that if I can't find a way make it work with a multi-level `[PSCustomObject]` (but I know there has to be lol)

Comment: You probably want to create a [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_function) for this, see e.g.: [Convert nested JSON array into separate columns in CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081131/1701026).

Comment: @iRon the `Flatten-Object` function definitely looks promising. Thanks!

I'll play with that and we'll see where it goes.