# Create unique variables in a loop powershell/Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I am trying save urls created from an array into unique variables created in a loop in a Jenkins freestyle project. I need to use these variables in the next step to send in an email.

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015303/dynamically-create-variables-in-powershell) answer to get the value of the variable `var$i` with the index `$i` we need to use this expression `Get-Variable -Name "var$i" -ValueOnly` .

So, to create the `env.properties` files with the keys as indexed variables and each containing it's repective url as value, I am using the following code. However, I get the error.

`var$i is not recognized as a cmdlet...` on this line. `var$i = [uri]::EscapeUriString($prefix+$files1[$i])` .

```
$files1 = @(Get-ChildItem c:\Users\rocky\Documents)
$count = ($files1).Count
$prefix="https://my.sharepoint.com/personal/abhishek/Documents/Desktop/"
for($i =0;$i -le $count; $i++){
    New-Variable -Name "var$i" -Value $i
    var$i = [uri]::EscapeUriString($prefix+$files1[$i])
    "var$i" = Get-Variable -Name "var$i" -ValueOnly | Out-File env.properties -Encoding ASCII
    
 }
```

What would be the correct way to create this?

The `env.properties` file is simply a key value pair. Inside it has Key Value pairs like so

```
Link1=https://example.com
Link2=https://example1.com
```

It appears I will have to write some groovy code in the body of the email itself. That would be better than to go with this avoidable idea.

Comment: [1] it is usually a REALLY bad idea to use auto-generated variable names. [*grin*] you normally otta leave them in a collection and use them that way. ///// [2] if you REALLY need to build a $Var name like that, try `var${Index}`. [*grin*] ///// [3] item `[2]` is a really really really bad idea. if you can avoid it ... avoid it.

Comment: As @Lee_Dailey points out, variable variable names are almost always the _wrong_ solution to whatever problem you're having. Please show an example of what the resulting `env.properties` file _should_ look like.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Updated the Question. Like the other person pointed out..it is a bad idea..so probably need to write some code in the email attachment plugin's email body to get these files out of the Jenkins workspace and create URLs.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it like this

```
$files1 =Get-ChildItem $ENV:WORKSPACE/ToscaPDFLogs
write-output $ENV:WORKSPACE
$linklist = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
$prefix="http://x.x.x.x:8080/job/OCM_Pipeline_OneDriveLink_Test_POC/ws/ToscaPDFLogs/"
foreach ($file in $files1) {
  $url1 = '<a href='+'"'+[uri]::EscapeUriString($prefix+$file.Name)+'">'+'PDF LINK'+'</a>'+'<br>'
  $null = $linklist.Add($url1) 
 }
```